# Assuming unique user names / logins, do I also need a unique userID number in the DB?

Tags: web-development, mysql

My users will login into a website using a login of their choosing, but which I will check against the DB to ensure unicity.  Given this, should I also have a unique userID in the DB?  This could be an autoincrement number and would be completely invisible to the users.

Thanks,

JDelage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique number is what we'd call a surrogate key (as opposed to a natural key, which would be some part of the actual data).

It is almost always advisable to use a surrogate key, the cases where it isn't are vanishingly small.

Also, I would recommend **against** using an auto-increment column.  It would be much better to use a GUID.  The main problem with an auto-increment is that you must insert the row into the database before you can know what the surrogate id is.  With GUID's, you can safely generate the surrogate id without consulting the database.  It will be difficult to change later if you go with an auto-increment column now.

Comment: If I understood properly what you are saying I think you are missing SQL functions like `LAST_INSERT_ID` that let you easily retrieve the last inserted id for an auto-increment field.

Comment: Nope, I don't think you are understanding exactly.  Needing to call `LAST_INSERT_ID` to get the id from the database is *exactly the problem*. It unnecessarily complicates the code, introduces extra round-trips to the DB, and it introduces **serious** complications scaling the application.  It's best to avoid auto-increment altogether and go with GUID's from day 1.  This is as close to universally true as you can get.

Comment: The problems created by relying on the database to provide you id's are numerous and severe. This responsibility should remain in the application code, there are just too many reasons to want that id immediately.

Comment: @qes: `The problems created by relying on the database to provide you id's are numerous and severe` could you provide a link or more explantions/examples? I don't see these problems. How can you think that using `LAST_INSERT_ID` is such a big problem, it requires a single easy query. I agree that is a bit more than creating the GUID before adding the row to the DB, but I don't see this as the big porblem you talk about. Moreover GUID are long numbers/strings, whilest an autoincrement starts form a singel digit number `1`.

Comment: What does the length have to do with anything?  Storage space? Irrelevant. Nice to look at? If it's relevant, then you shouldn't be using the surrogate id regardless of whether it's a guid or int. As for the problems, they mostly involve scaling - whether that's horizontally partitioning your data or distributing pieces and using messaging. Requiring the DB to give you back a key makes it a bottleneck, and not just performance wise. Will your site scale and will this become and issue?  Maybe, maybe not. But there's no significant downside, so just do it right from the start.

Comment: Here's one article I picked because it's Spolsky, there's more info in the comments and linked-to pages than his post: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html

Comment: It may be a hard point to appreciate without having switched a handful of applications from using AUTO_ID to GUID in order to drop the constraints associated with auto.  Having done that more than once, I would never design a new DB with auto incrementing ids as the primary key.

Comment: OK.  @qes - do you have a strong opinion on how to generate and store a GUID?

Comment: Use whatever facility exists in your language to generate a new GUID, store them in a GUID column if the storage engine has one, otherwise char is good.

Comment: @qes: Thanks for sharing the interesting article you picked I read also the article suggested there to be read (http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-i-choose-for-my-primary-key.html) which greatly explains the pros/cons of each solution. And makes me think that (1) either you have NOT read it or (2) you have never wrote a string comparison function...

Comment: @qes: ...following from above: (1) if you read the article it clearly says that among the other cons there is a drop in performance that is not only about space as you think: `the wider datatype leads to a drop in index performance`. (2) If you ever wrote a string comaprison function you should know that for how much you can improve its performance doing `(inta == intb)` will always be extremly faster than doing `(stringa == stringb)`. So guess the fatigue of the DB when you do a huge join on multiple tables.

Comment: @JDelage: unless your app will ever need to be distributed on multiple DBs (which I doubt), you will soon regreat to have added everywhere IDs that looks like this `C87FC84A-EE47-47EE-842C-29E969AC5131`, for both performance reasons and definitely for cumbersome debug reasons.

Comment: Do some profiling and then come back and tell me how much slower it is in reality. It is exceptionally foolhardy to think the performance of an int comparison vs a 128 bit binary comparison outweighs the problems with requiring a round trip to the db to get you id.  You are also misunderstanding the scenarios in which an auto incrementing int will becoming problematic - it will as soon as any part of your app lives on a different machine from the DB - not just when you introduce multiple db's - only the simplest and smallest of apps can remain as an app & db on the same machine.

Comment: int vs. guid comparison is a **micro** optimization.  If you have enough traffic to warrant such optimizations, you would in an extremely high percentage of scenarios gain **far more** performance by scaling and distributing the workload, something that will then require large scale re-architecting if you used auto incrementing integer primary keys.  Been there, done that.  Have you?

Answer (score 2):

Its always good to have an ID which autoincrements as you put new users in your DB. In the future you might need it. And it will ensure that there are no replicates in your DB and your program doesn't fail while logging in. You can make this the primary one also.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you clarify "In the future you might need it."?

Comment: the answer by Ammar Alakkad is great. thats what you might need sometime when building an application. and also once you make your framework for the app, it will be very hard for you to change it in the future. specially if its going to be open source or you need to make big changes to your program in the future. you wouldn't be able to tell all your users to again sign up on your site. rather keep some places where you can improve in the future.

Comment: ???

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to do that, you may want to link it with foreign keys from other tables or to do queries that contains something like:

> "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` > 1000"

When dealing with primary keys it's very handy if it were numbers.

Comment: +1 Excellent example of why numerical keys are good to have

Comment: @John: I wouldn't consider that a good example at all.  What logical purpose would such a query serve?  Any purpose I can conceive would be better served with a different piece of data (e.g., CreatedOn). Surrogate keys are there *only* to serve as an immutable unique key. There are also very real and significant limitations with an auto-increment column. GUID's don't suffer those issues, and if one really wanted ordering could be at least partially provided with a comb strategy for GUID generation.

Comment: @qes: totally agree, I've never seen a query more useless than the one provided as an example in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your user is **not allowed to ever change the user name** he chooses the 1st time, and you are absolutly sure that **you will never give the user the possibilty to change such user name for the rest of his life**, you could also just use this user name as a unique primary key.

This is not the case when user name is the email itself, it would be nosense to not allow the user to change it ever.

You can find best answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466553/use-of-an-id-in-databases